# What are phase constants in equation of electric field for deriving law of reflection at boundary of dielectric?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, dielectric

I'm studying reflection of EM Waves at dielectric boundary from Optics by Eugene Hecht. But despite many attempts I am unable to understand

> What is meant by statement "Here ϵ<sub>r</sub> and ϵ<sub>t</sub> are phase constant relative to E<sub>I</sub> and are introduced because **position is not unique.**"?

**Picture from book**:

[image: Page 112 Optics by Eugene Hecht]

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually one can shift the expression along the interface. For instance, consider the transformation 
$$ \mathbf{r} \rightarrow \mathbf{r} + \mathbf{r}_0 $$
where $\mathbf{r}_0$ is a vector lying in the plane of the interface. Then the term in the argument would become
$$ \mathbf{k}_x\cdot\mathbf{r} \rightarrow \mathbf{k}_x\cdot\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{k}_x\cdot\mathbf{r}_0 , $$
where the subsript $x$ is either $r$ or $t$. Here $\mathbf{k}_x\cdot\mathbf{r}_0$ is a constant. Since one can do any such shift this constant represents an unspecified phase. Therefore , one should include these arbitrary phases.

Answer (score 0):

$\epsilon_r$ and $\epsilon_t$ appear to be phase terms to shift the reference plane of the reflection. If the reference plane or origin was chosen to be the interface then $\epsilon_r$ , $\epsilon_t$ $=0$. However, if you chose a reference plane that was not at the interface then you would add a phase term $\epsilon_r$ , $\epsilon_t$ $\neq$ $0$.  These values should be proportional to the distance from the interface and the $\vec{k}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: @flippiefanus is correct. If you are considering cases besides normal incidence. (Which you should.)  Then there will be non-zero phase differences at different points along the boundary.